# Adding new elements to XML

Tags: xml, delphi

Here is my Xml

```
<Cars>
<Car id="1" name="Opel" picture="\File\JPEG\opel.jpg" />
<Car id="2" name="Ford" picture="\File\JPEG\ford.jpg"  />
<Car id="3" name="Volvo" picture="\File\JPEG\volvo.jpg" />
</Cars>
```

Now I want to add new cars

```
Listbox1     Listbox2 
(CarName)   (Car.Picture)
 BMW        \File\JPEG\bmw.jpg
Mercedes    \File\JPEG\Merdedes.jpg
```

Problem I have with car.Id. Each id  must be unique (+1)
Having already 3 cars in the file how to make every other car id +1

My code

```
    var
    lNewCar: IXMLCarType;
      i, NewID : Integer;
      begin
      i:= 0;
      NewID := 1 + MaxID (Form1.Memo1.Lines.Text);
      while ( i < ListBox1.Count) and  ( i < ListBox2.Count) 
      begin
        lNewCar := XMLIntf.Cars.add;
        lNewCar.id   := NewID;
        lNewCar.name := Listbox1.Items[i];
        lNewCar.jpeg := Listbox2.Items[i];
       Inc(i);
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Why don't you just find the highest existing ID (e.g. using an XPath query on the XML) and then just add 1 to it?

Comment: Because I do not know.Can you give an example?

Comment: See my answer I've just posted.

Comment: Btw, your edit to include my code has completely changed what you are asking about.  You should revert your q t how it was before that edit, and then post a new q about the AV.  But before you do that, see stackoverflow.com/help/mcve because your new q will need to include an MCVE - and note the "Complete" in "MCVE"

Answer (score 2):

In view of the simple structure of your XML, just a series of `Car` nodes below a `Cars` root node, you can find the maximum existing `id` attribute value by iterating the `Car` nodes and examining their `id` attributes, like this:

Sample project:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    btnMaxId: TButton;
    procedure btnMaxIdClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

function MaxId(const XML : String) : Integer;
[...]
var
  Form1: TForm1;
implementation
[...]
procedure TForm1.btnMaxIdClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(MaxID(Memo1.Lines.Text)));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('<Cars>');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('  <Car id="1" name="Opel" picture="\File\JPEG\opel.jpg" />');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('  <Car id="98" name="Ford" picture="\File\JPEG\ford.jpg"  />');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('  <Car id="3" name="Volvo" picture="\File\JPEG\volvo.jpg" />');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('</Cars>');
end;

function MaxId(const XML : String) : Integer;
var
  XmlDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  NodeList : IXmlDOMNodeList;
  Node : IXMLDomNode;
  i : Integer;
  ID : Integer;
  ErrorCode : Integer;
  S : String;
begin
  Result := 0;
  XmlDoc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
  try
    XmlDoc.Async := False;
    XmlDoc.LoadXml(XML);

    NodeList := XmlDoc.DocumentElement.childNodes;
    for i := 0 to NodeList.Length - 1 do begin
      Node := NodeList.item[i];
      S := Node.attributes.GetNamedItem('id').nodeValue;
      Val(S, ID, ErrorCode);
      if ErrorCode = 0 then begin
        if ID > Result then
          Result := ID;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    XmlDoc := Nil;
  end;
end;

end.
```

You need to pass your XML document as a string to this `MaxID` function. So, if the XML in your q were in a TMemo component on a form, you could use it like this:

```
var
  NewID : integer;
begin
  NewID := 1 + MaxID (Form1.Memo1.Lines.Text);
  lNewExpression.id := NewID;
```

There is a more direct way of getting the maximum value of an attribute, see e.g. [How to find the max attribute from an XML document using Xpath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702039/how-to-find-the-max-attribute-from-an-xml-document-using-xpath-1-0)
but that requires some familiarity with XPath queries and you would need to note what it says about getting the maximum value of a multi-character `id`.

Comment: Access violation... wrrr :(  But, thank you very much

Comment: The compiler does not report a bug. Only in the project(.exe) is the error pops up. Access Violation at address......
When I give ButtonClick - my code (you look up (uptade) my Code)

Comment: The comiler wouldn't report a bug.  An AV is a run-time error, not a compile -time one.  Run your app and when the AV happens, go to View | Debug Windows | Call stack.  The top line in the pop-up is where the AV occurred.  Or, use F7 and F8 to single-step  execution until the AV occurs.  Btw, this stuff is **so** elementary that I'm slightly amazed you seem to have no clue how to identify where the error is occurring, never mind finding its cause.

Comment: NodeList := XmlDoc.DocumentElement.childNodes;

Comment: Then either XMLDoc or XMLDoc.DocumentElement or  XmlDoc.DocumentElement.childNodes is Nil.  Use Ctrl-F5 to determine which.  My guess is that you aren't passing a value XML string to `MaxId`.

Comment: XMLDoc.DocumentElement   value = nil

Comment: In that case, most likely you are not passing a valid XML string to `MaxId`.

Comment: Maybe this is the cause?:   `XMLIntf := GetDictionar(self.XMLDocument1);
    XMLIntf: IXMLTransportType;`

Comment: I am not wasting time  looking at code quoted without any context - you could easily post the value of the parameter you are passing to MaxId but chose not to for some reason.  Like I said in my comment to to your q, post a new q written as an MCVE and revert this q to how it was.  Until then, I've voted to close this q.

Comment: I have updated my answer so that it contains a self-contained project which shows how to get the MaxId value from some XML.  That is all I am doing.