# Finding the xml element attribute with the max value causes parse error

Tags: xml, xslt

I am coding xslt to find the max row value of an element 'item' as the example shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537533/calculating-element-max-attribute-value-fails-using-xslt-and-xpath/64537794#64537794). And per suggestions received, I tried code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702039/how-to-find-the-max-attribute-from-an-xml-document-using-xpath-1-0). However the '<=' operator causes parse error:

```
./ui.xsl:16: parser error : Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values                           
                                              not(@column < preceding-sibling::i
```

When I wrote code as:

```
  <xsl:variable name="maxRow" select="/ui/layout/item
                                            [
                                              not(@row <= preceding-sibling::item/@row) and
                                              not(@row <= following-sibling::item/@row)
                                            ]/@row" />
```

After I change the code to:

```
  <xsl:variable name="maxRow" select="/ui/layout/item
                                            [
                                              not(preceding-sibling::item/@row > @row) and
                                              not(following-sibling::item/@row > @row)
                                            ]/@row" />
```

The code starts to work just fine. I am using xsltproc as my processor. I believe '<=' is a standard XPATH 1.0 operator. How come it's not recognized by the processor?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with XPath, but rather with XML. The reason is described in the [XML 1.0 specification, Section "Start-Tags"](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-STag). A Start-Tag is defined as follows:

```
STag       ::=      '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
Attribute  ::=      Name Eq AttValue 
... (following the link to 'AttValue')
AttValue   ::=      '"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"'
                 |  "'" ([^<&'] | Reference)* "'"
```

As you can see in the above rule, the *AttValue* definition excludes both chars, `<` and `&`. They cannot be part of the attribute value. The latter is only allowed as part of the *Reference* rule. Normally, both chars have to be escaped as *Entity References* according to [these rules (WikiPedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping).

Additional info:

> Note:
> Although the EntityValue production allows the definition of a general entity consisting of a single explicit **`<`** in the literal (e.g., `<!ENTITY mylt "<">`), it is strongly advised to avoid this practice since any reference to that entity will cause a well-formedness error.

**Summary:** You cannot use the char `<` in an attribute value in XML.
**Affirmation:** Your solution of inverting the comparison is the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can invert the logic and use `>` as [suggested by @zx485](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64547928/290085), or you can just use `&lt;` or `&lt;=`.